# Do smart pointers delete memory defined by new

Tags: c++, new-operator, smart-pointers

In the following code example, does the destructor of the shared pointer delete the object that's been destructed defined by *new*?

`auto object = std::shared_ptr<Foo>(new Foo());`

I found this in some legacy code and I'm wondering if this causes memleaks or not.

Comment: Yes, it does that

Comment: @Wander3r To clarify: It does delete the memory. It does not cause memory leaks.

Comment: @MaxLanghof Didn't realize there's an opposite question to what's asked in the title :)

Comment: *"I found this in some legacy code"* C++11 is already legacy...

Comment: @Jarod42 Arguably using the pattern `shared_ptr<T>(new T)` *is* legacy code, since you’re supposed to use `make_shared<T>()` unless there’s a specific reason against it.